# How to make string appear first in order by in linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

How can I do the following SQL statement using Linq?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY 
CASE myColumnName
WHEN 'Cats' THEN 1
WHEN 'Bear' THEN 2
ELSE 99
END, myColumnName
```

If myColumnName contains a list of animals and I want to sort by that column, but want Cats to appear first in the results then bears, is this possible to do this with a Linq statement?

Comment: What's the problem - just create C# conditional expression, e.g. `from x in myTable orderby x.myColumnName == "Cats" ? 1 : x.myColumnName == "Bear" ? 2 : 99 select x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
var res = from p in context.myTable
          let oOrder = ( p.myColumnName == "Cats" ? 1 :
                         p.myColumnName == "Bear" ? 2 : 99)
          orderby oOrder, p.myColumnName
          select p;
```

Comment: Don't forget to order by the column's value if it's not cats or bears.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

A direct translation might look like this:

```
myTable
    .OrderBy(t => 
        t.MyColumnName == "Cats" ? 1
        : t.MyColumnName == "Bears" ? 2
        : 99)
    .ThenBy(t => t.MyColumnName)
```